# Check if emojis is disabled

Tags: emoji

How can check if the emoji is disabled on the site or not?

I have searched for an official function but I haven't found anything officially, We are creating a theme and will publish it soon and need to check if the customer has disabled the emojis by adding any function or by any another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely remove emojis this is the code:

```
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 ); 
    remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' ); 
    remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' ); 
    remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
```

So to check if any of those are active you could use `has_action()` like this:

```
    $emoji_script front = has_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
    if( $emoji_script_front ) {
      // The emoji script is loaded on the front end
    }
```

You could do different things for each of the actions. `has_action` does not care about priority, and this should work in the functions.php file since it runs later than all of those actions.

[More about has_action() on WordPress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_action/)

Comment: WooW Thank you very much you are amazing.

Comment: Keep in mind that "disabling emojis" is not actually preventing anyone from using emojis. It just disables the functionality that WordPress uses to support emojis on older browsers that don't support them natively.

Comment: Like my personal emoji stamp };]